# Write a function to print the sum which takes the parameter in this wa: sum(2)(3) and outputs 5

Tags: javascript

Write a function to print the sum which takes the parameter in this way: sum(2)(3) and outputs 5

Comment: can we see what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can achieve just like this

```
function sum(x) {
    return y => {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

But it's kind of lack of extensibility.
If you want to calculate `sum(2)(3)(5)`, this function just doesn't work.

You have to change it to

```
function sum(x) {
    return y => {
        return z => {
           return x + y + z;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a common solution, combining recursion and a little trick.

```
function sum(x) {
    var result = x;
    function adder(y) {
        result += y;
        return adder;
    }
    adder.toString = function() {
        return result;
    };
    return adder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is functional currying.

ES6

```
let sum = (first) => (second) => first + second;
```

ES5

```
function sum(first){ return function(second){  return first + second;}}

sum(2)(3);  //returns 5
```